# Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.175 Scroll View Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU

Tags: xamarin

After upgrading Forms from 2.3.2.127 my app began to crash. After downgrading the Forms to 2.3.2.127 the issue went away, and I did try 2.3.3.193 and the issue happens there as well.

I have included a link to a PCL test app that will recreate this issue if anyone has any idea as to what I could be doing wrong or some type of workaround that would be great.

Once you start the app you will notice the tab page shows up oddly, if you navigate to the menu and select any of the items the app will crash when it attempts to load that page and render the scroll view. You will also see this exception thrown java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for ScrollViewRenderer

[PCL test app zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmJbamy7G-2ThFl52Q-7jeliVy8d)